# Installing a package by pip in venv environment installs it into local not virtual environmennt. Wny?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

In the console I create a virtual env with the command below/
`python3 -m venv ENV`
Then,
`pip install requests`.
This does not install `requests` in `ENV`. Why is that happening?

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: Yes I did.. I was wondering if I should always `python3 -m pip3 install ***** `

Comment: Then you must have python2 installed on the same machine.
You could just activate the virtual environment and then use pip3 install <package>

Comment: Let me learn the basics thank you chumbaloo.